# One-to-one mapping with primary key (got an exceptions)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to mapping One-to-one with a primary key. I have created two entity classes (person, passport). Tables and columns are created but data is not inserting it is saying empty set in commandline client when I am checking.

Exceptions: 1) Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [Naresh] value by reflection : [class com.project.oto.entity.Passport.pno] setter of com.project.oto.entity.Passport.pno

2. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.project.oto.entity.Passport.pno to java.lang.String
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

I have attached my project screenshots below and IDK what is the issue could you please help me with the issue.

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you explain the what pno represents and what you wanted to achieve with the generator?

Comment: Actually, the issue was resolved.

The issue was with the id annotation in person entity previously I haven't declared that annotation in proper place.

Comment: You can't use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`. `Passport` has an `Integer` id whereas `Person` has a `String` id.